# Remove backslash from nested json

Tags: json, python-3.x, encode

I have a response from a data base request saved in a list and sent as a parameter `response` to following function:

**phython3**

```
def sendReponse(status, myStatusCode, message, response):
if myStatusCode == 200:
    cleaned = json.loads(response)
      #       {
      #      "instanceIdJobCreator": "instance-x44",
      #      "component": "mapper",
      #      "jobParameter": "{\"alice\":\"bob\",\"foo\":\"bar\",\"va1\":\"bmw-x-5\"}",
      #      "jobStatus": "created",
      #      "itemType": "job",
      #      "createTime": "2019-07-06T14:57:31.577Z",
      #      "id": "job-1GXSBjK1pI-b9gs88Azwv-BCvkU-mO6"
      #       }
    data = {"status": status, 
            "info": message,
            "data": cleaned
            }
else:
    data = {"status": status, 
            "info": message
            }
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
message = dict(statusCode=myStatusCode,
            isBase64Encoded=False,
            headers=headers,
            body=data)
return message
```

The issue I have now is that the nested items in ""jobParamter" have backslash added:

```
"jobParameter": "{\"alice\":\"bob\",\"foo\":\"bar\",\"va1\":\"bmw-x-5\"}"
```

Is there a way to remove them? I already stried to response.replace('\"','"'), but for some reason the response string didn't replace the backslashes...

Comment: That's a nested JSON document. Decode that string as JSON too. **You don't need to remove backslashes**.

Comment: The backslashes are **not actually in the value**, they are there to present you with a valid Python expression.

Comment: How do I do that when the string is inside "response"-document?

Comment: You don't. You have `cleaned`, and `cleaned["jobParameter"]` is the nested JSON value. `json.loads(cleaned["jobParameter"])` decodes it.